# List structure has changed error in Datasheet mode - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, list-view, datasheet, production

We have a custom list that we are trying to edit in Datasheet view and are getting the following error when the next row is clicked:

> Another user has changed the structure of this list. All your pending
>   changes to this list will be discarded. To retrieve the latest copy of
>   the list, click Refresh.

This issue is happening only in the Production environment. We have checked with same data in QA and Dev. But we don't get any issue in QA or Dev. That means it's nothing related to data I guess. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this happen if you try to add a record in a view that doesn't contain all the "required" fields.  If you want to add a record you'll need to do that on a view that has all the required fields in "All Items" view.

Answer (score 1):

Check below methods:

1. This happens when another person tries to add or delete a column from the list while you are edit content in datasheet view. If you are consistently getting this error, it will help to use the ribbon to switch to "standard view" then back to "datasheet view" to allow the changes to 'sync up'. It's important to realize the possibility that not all columns in the list are visible in the datasheet view.
2. Try to remove check-box columns from the view. Here the user has created a custom checkbox column which was causing the issue:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.sharepoint.portalserver.development/t0MsruWw-Ac

3. Removing comma in hyperlinks:

https://bmerri19.wordpress.com/

Some users provide their methods in below article, check if there is a method useful for you(The article is for SP2007, but also useful for SP2010):

[Unable to save changes in Datasheet View](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14648/unable-to-save-changes-in-datasheet-view)